# issue with styling over a slide show

Tags: html, css, coding-style

Hey guys so I am styling up a content body over a jquery slider I built.....my issue is I need some pictures to have a `float: left` so they line up with each other but the parent has a `margin: -6em 0 0 0;` and if I add the `float:left` it goes out of the parent div......HTML:

```
 <div id="Content">
        <div class="main_Body">
            <div class="top-halfCont">
                <div class="online_training">
                    <div class="training_image">
                        <img src="images/onlinetraining_home_03.png" width="75" height="75" />
                    </div><!-- .training_image -->
                </div><!-- .online_training -->
                <div class="background_check">
                    <div class="background_image">
                        <img src="images/background_check_home_03.png" width="75" height="75" />
                    </div><!-- .background_image -->
                </div><!-- .background_check -->
                <div class="uninsured_alert">
                    <div class="uninsured_alert_image">
                        <img src="images/unisuredalert_system_03.png" width="75" height="75" />
                    </div><!-- .uninsured_alert_image -->
                </div><!-- .uninsured_alert -->
            </div><!-- .top-halfCont -->
        </div><!-- .main_Body -->
    </div><!-- #Content -->
```

Style:

```
/* main content #Content */
#Content {
    display:block;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;  
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 13px #888888;
}
.main_Body {
    display:block;  
    margin: -6em 0 0 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
.online_training {
    display:block;
    width:200px;    
}
.training_image {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
.background_check {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
}
.background_image {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
.uninsured_alert {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
}
.uninsured_alert_image {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
```

Comment: I think I understand your question. I've made a jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AgGuH/ What i've done is removed all the `width` settings that you have on the child `divs`. I've then added a 6em margin on `.top-halfCont` to offset the -6em you have on the `.main_Body`

Comment: how do want the images to be aligned? horizontal or vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include the follwing changes

```
.top-halfCont{
    margin:6em 0 0 0;
}
.main_Body {
    display:block;  
    margin: -6em 0 0 0;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow:auto;
}
```